# javascript variable into php that is already into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, variables

i have tried this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = 0;
    document.getElementById('text').value = "<?php echo phpVal[s];?>";
</script>
```

the problem is  how can i put the (s) value into (PHP) code.

Here's more context:

```
<head>
<?php $s = ["a","b","c"]; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doFun(ss){
    var data = "<?php echo json_encode($s); ?>";
    document.getElementById('t').value = s[ss];
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="t" name="t" />
<button type="button" id="b" name="b" onclick="doFun(0)">doFun</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve the impossible? It is like mixing oil with water.

Comment: @invisal why it's impossible !!

Comment: because you cannot mix the server-side script with client-side script. Of course, there are workaround but none of them truly mixing the code together.

Comment: @invisal with json encoding you can do the impossible ... try it if you want ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, by the time `s` has a value (on the *client*), the PHP code (on the *server*) has long-since completed.

What you do instead depends a **lot** on what your end goal is. You have a lot of options. Here are two of them:

1. Output the entire `phpVal` array/object to the client, and then index into it with `s`.

   ```
   var s = 0;
   var data = <?php echo json_encode(phpVal)%>;
   document.getElementById('text').value = data[s];
   ```
2. Send `s` to the server via ajax, have the PHP code that runs in response to *that* request pick out the correct value from `phpVal`, and return that as the result of the ajax, putting it in the client-side `input`'s `value`. For example:

   JavaScript:

   ```
   var s = 0;
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
           document.getElementById('text').value = xhr.responseText;
       }
   };
   xhr.open("get-value.php?s=" + encodeURIComponent(s));
   // You don't really need this ^
   // for `0`, but many times when sending variables to the
   // server, you do
   xhr.send();
   ```

   PHP for `get-value.php` (*roughly*):

   ```
   <?php
   header('Content-Type: text/plain');
   $phpVal = /*...get the value however it is you do that...*/
   echo $phpVal[$_GET['s']];
   ?>
   ```

But again it depends on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: this solution maybe help but i don't need to connect with server and bring data ... i already have an array and i want to put it's value into (s) depend on the index that i want to send ... e.g.

Comment: <head>
    <?php
      $s = ["a","b","c"];
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function doFun(ss){
           var data = "<?php echo json_encode($s); ?>";
           document.getElementById('t').value = s[ss];
         }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <input type="text" id="t" name="t" />
     <button type="button" id="b" name="b" onclick="doFun(0)">doFun</button>
</body>

Comment: @Anas: To improve/clarify your question, use the "edit" link on the question. As you can see, code in comments is not really readable. *Edit:* I've done it for you this time.

Comment: @Anas: *"i already have an array"* You have an array ***on the server***. If you want it on the client, you need to send it to the client (for instance, #1 above).

Comment: i used the first answer with json encoding ... actually i used json with mobile application but i tried here many ways to achieve my goad but nothing work except json ... anyway thank you sir for your answer and please if you can edit it because it should be  
'var data = <?php echo json_encode($phpVal)?>;'    not     'var data = <?php echo json_encode(phpVal)%>;' ^_^